# yocto building linux kernel module

Tags: linux, yocto

help please, I meet with a problem with assembling the kernel module, created a new layer

```
$ ll ~/work/yocto/sources/meta-gobinet
total 28K
drwxr-xr-x  5 ivr ivr 4.0K Aug 18 11:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 ivr ivr 4.0K Aug 18 11:26 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 ivr ivr 4.0K Aug 18 11:26 conf
-rw-r--r--  1 ivr ivr 1.1K Aug 18 11:26 COPYING.MIT
-rw-r--r--  1 ivr ivr  801 Aug 18 11:26 README
drwxr-xr-x  3 ivr ivr 4.0K Aug 18 11:26 recipes-example
drwxr-xr-x  3 ivr ivr 4.0K Aug 18 11:28 recipes-gobinet
```

and i was create recipe

```
$ cat ~/work/yocto/sources/meta-gobinet/recipes-gobinet/gobinet/gobinet_1.bb 
SUMMARY = "gobinet module"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
inherit module
SRC_URI = "file://gobinet.tar.xz;md5sum=13b5f20214a3925eb4be3b831b62612f"
#SRC_URI += " file://0001_gobinet_makefile.patch;md5sum=1261df573e1b91177954f6190a12c7b1"
```

and i put gobinet.tar.xz in

```
$ ll ~/work/yocto/sources/meta-gobinet/recipes-gobinet/gobinet/gobinet/
total 44K
drwxr-xr-x 2 ivr ivr 4.0K Aug 18 15:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 ivr ivr 4.0K Aug 18 15:31 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 ivr ivr  30K Aug 18 15:31 gobinet.tar.xz
```

content of gobinet.tar.xz is

```
tar -xf gobinet.tar.xz 
ivr@home-machine:~/work/yocto/sources/meta-gobinet/recipes-gobinet/gobinet/gobinet
$ ll gobinet
total 244K
drwxr-xr-x 2 ivr ivr 4.0K Aug 17 21:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 ivr ivr 4.0K Aug 18 15:39 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 ivr ivr 3.1K Aug 17 21:32 GobiNetworkManager.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 ivr ivr  36K Aug 17 21:32 GobiUSBNet.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 ivr ivr  131 Aug 17 21:32 Kconfig
-rw-r--r-- 1 ivr ivr  324 Aug 17 21:32 kernel-deploy-guide
-rw-r--r-- 1 ivr ivr  326 Aug 17 21:32 Makefile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ivr ivr  127 Aug 17 21:32 Makefile.kernel
-rw-r--r-- 1 ivr ivr  36K Aug 17 21:32 QMI.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 ivr ivr  97K Aug 17 21:32 QMIDevice.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 ivr ivr 9.8K Aug 17 21:32 QMIDevice.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 ivr ivr 8.7K Aug 17 21:32 QMI.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 ivr ivr 2.9K Aug 17 21:32 Readme.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 ivr ivr  13K Aug 17 21:32 Structs.h
```

but i have error

```
ERROR: gobinet-1-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: gobinet-1-r0 do_compile: Execution of '/home/ivr/work/yocto/build/tmp/work/phyboard_segin_imx6ul_6-phytec-linux-gnueabi/gobinet/1-r0/temp/run.do_compile.1734076' failed with exit code 1:
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/ivr/work/yocto/build/tmp/work/phyboard_segin_imx6ul_6-phytec-linux-gnueabi/gobinet/1-r0/temp/log.do_compile.1734076
```

writes that there is no Makefile but Makefile is present.
tell me what is the problem? I'm already tired, but I can't figure out what is missing for this complex assembly system

Answer (score -1):

You don't have any action of compile and install (*do_compile()* and *do_install()*) in your *.bb file. Please analyze and try this example.

---

**Create a Simple "Hello, World!" Example Recipe**

**1. Create a directory to store your application in the meta layer:**

```
cd sources/meta-<custom_layer>
mkdir -p recipes-<custom_recipe_dir>/hello-world/hello-world
```

*Replace <custom_recipe_dir> with your preferred name.*

**2. Create the recipe (.bb file) for the application:**

```
cd sources/meta-<custom_layer>/recipes-<custom_recipe_dir>/hello-world/
touch hello-world_1.0.0.bb
```

Then, add the following instructions to the recipe:

*~/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-<custom_layer>/recipes-<custom_recipe_dir>/hello-world/hello-world_1.0.0.bb*

```
SUMMARY = "A simple Hello World application"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
SRC_URI = "file://hello_world.c"

TARGET_CC_ARCH += "${LDFLAGS}"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() {
  ${CC} -Wall hello-world.c -o hello-world
}

do_install() {
  install -d ${D}${bindir}
  install -m 0755 ${S}/hello-world ${D}${bindir}
}
```

**3. Create a simple C programming language source file that prints "Hello, World!":**

```
cd $SDIR/meta-<custom_layer>/recipes-<custom_recipe_dir>/hello-world/hello-world/
touch hello_world.c
```

Then, add the following source code to the file:

*~/var-flsc-yocto/sources/meta-<custom_layer>/recipes-<custom_recipe>/hello-world/src/hello_world.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello, World!\n");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**4. Open the local.conf file:**

*~/var-fslc-yocto/build/conf/local.conf*

Then, add the following line at the end of the file, to include the package in any image you will build next:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " hello-world"
```

**5. Build your image (for example core-image-base):**

```
cd ~/your-yocto-fslc/build/
bitbake core-image-base
```

The "Hello, World!" application will be installed to /usr/bin/hello-world, as defined in the do_install() function of the recipe above.

Example base on Variscite Blog: [Creating a custom Yocto BSP Layer](https://www.variscite.com/blog/creating-a-custom-yocto-bsp-layer/)

Comment: inherit module provide those build / install functions.